# Carousel with truncated previous and next images by using Bxslider and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bxslider

I am making responsive simple carousal for computer and touch device by using [Bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) plugin and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) .

I am looking for [carousel with truncated previous and next images](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/) to add in this page. 
Wnt to achieve in like [this page](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/). Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**
     
        
        
            
            BX Slider

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swipe/css/normalize.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css">

    <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="row col-lg-10" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="image/banner1.png" title="Funky roots" /></li>
      <li><img src="image/banner1.png" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
      <li><img src="image/banner1.png" title="Happy trees" /></li>
    </ul>
                   <!--######################### End Swipe Carousel ##############################-->
    </section>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: 'horizontal',
      captions: true,
      auto: true,
      touchEnabled: true,
      oneToOneTouch: true,
     /* controls: false,*/

      pager: false,
      speed: 200
    });

    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Want to achieve this http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

Comment: There;s a solution with bootstrap 3 https://gist.github.com/allcaps/4525c0150a14ef3d9985